# Change the date format of a column and check if it matches yesterday's date

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to copy the row in sheet A where column H is yesterday's date and add it to the bottom of sheet B.

I have the following process in mind.

1. Get yesterday's date
2. Get the date in column H of sheet A
3. Check for rows that match yesterday's date and sheet A's column H
4. Get the rows that match
5. Get Sheet B
6. Add a row to the bottom of sheet B
7. Output at the bottom of sheet B

Now we are stuck at 3.
I was able to change yesterday's date to the yyyy/MM/dd format, but I can't figure out how to change the date in column H of sheet A to the yyyy/MM/dd format.

I used Utilities.formatDate to change yesterday's date to yyyy/MM/dd format.
Column H on sheet A gave me an error when I used Utilities.formatDate. I believe it is due to the format of column H on sheet A.
How can I get column H on sheet A to be in yyyy/mm/dd format as well?

Best Regards,

The following is the code we are currently working on.

```js
function code() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet A');
  let yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
  yesterday = Utilities.formatDate(yesterday,"JST", "yyyy/MM/dd");

  let range = sheet.getRange('H:H').getValues();

  console.log(yesterday)
  console.log(range)
}
```

> console.log(yesterday) = 2021/05/11

> console.log(range) = Logging output too large.
> [ Thu Apr 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Fri Apr 02 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Sat Apr 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Sun Apr 04 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Mon Apr 05 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Tue Apr 06 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Wed Apr 07 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Thu Apr 08 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Fri Apr 09 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Sat Apr 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Sun Apr 11 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Mon Apr 12 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Tue Apr 13 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Wed Apr 14 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Thu Apr 15 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Fri Apr 16 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Sat Apr 17 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Sun Apr 18 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Mon Apr 19 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Tue Apr 20 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Wed Apr 21 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Thu Apr 22 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Fri Apr 23 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Sat Apr 24 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Sun Apr 25 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Mon Apr 26 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Tue Apr 27 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Wed Apr 28 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Thu Apr 29 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Fri Apr 30 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Sat May 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Sun May 02 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Mon May 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Tue May 04 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Wed May 05 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Thu May 06 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Fri May 07 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Sat May 08 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Sun May 09 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Mon May 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Tue May 11 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Thu Apr 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],
> [ Fri Apr 02 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time) ],

Comment: Please include the code you have so far and the data to double check and to understand exactly what you are trying to do, as from the description its not so clear.

Comment: Maybe its because what is in column H is not formatted as a date but as text, is this possible?

Comment: @iansedano I have added the code.  
Column H of sheet A is in date format, but it contains information that is not needed, as shown in console.log(range).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to copy all rows from one sheet to another if the date value is yesterday.

I made some sample data that looked like this:

| Name | Value | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Harry Powell | 0.736 | A | A | A | A | A | 4/13/2166 |
| John Carter | 0.124 | B | B | B | B | B | 5/11/2021 |
| Patricia Stewart | 0.256 | C | C | C | C | C | 11/2/2032 |
| Gregory Parker | 0.322 | A | A | A | A | A | 11/24/1973 |
| Nicholas Barnes | 0.456 | B | B | B | B | B | 6/27/2051 |
| Helen Thomas | 0.061 | C | C | C | C | C | 10/15/1942 |
| Anthony Morris | 0.542 | A | A | A | A | A | 3/13/2090 |
| Brian James | 0.569 | B | B | B | B | B | 5/11/2021 |
| Ruth Collins | 0.804 | C | C | C | C | C | 5/5/1904 |
| Philip Clark | 0.692 | A | A | A | A | A | 7/9/1927 |
| Brenda Cook | 0.093 | B | B | B | B | B | 10/23/2130 |
| William Watson | 0.185 | C | C | C | C | C | 5/11/2021 |
| Theresa Walker | 0.407 | A | A | A | A | A | 8/12/2026 |
| Gloria Lewis | 0.851 | B | B | B | B | B | 3/7/1916 |
| Linda Richardson | 0.319 | C | C | C | C | C | 5/11/2021 |
| Virginia Edwards | 0.133 | A | A | A | A | A | 5/11/2021 |
| Ruby Roberts | 0.964 | B | B | B | B | B | 6/30/1989 |
| Rose Anderson | 0.287 | C | C | C | C | C | 2/6/1966 |

Date is in Column H.

This was in "Sheet A" and there was another sheet called "Sheet B" with only the headers.

The goal is for all those rows with dates 5/11/2021 (today being 5/12/2021), to be copied to the bottom of "Sheet B".

#### Modified script with comments

```
function code() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet A');
  const yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
  
  // Everything up to here is fine

  // yesterday = Utilities.formatDate(yesterday,"JST", "yyyy/MM/dd"); // You could use this to output the date, it doesn't seem so practical to me to use it for comparison

  const yestYear = yesterday.getFullYear()
  const yestMonth = yesterday.getMonth()
  const yestDate = yesterday.getDate()

  // let range = sheet.getRange('H:H').getValues(); // This just gets the one row, better to get everything in one go

  // This detects all data in the sheet and creates a range to get everything.
  // It is assumed that you have data in column A
  // If not, you'll have to adjust the index position to get the date below
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 

  values.shift() // This removes the first row from the values (headers)

  const filteredDates = values.filter(row => {
    // Assuming that the Dates are always in column H (8th column, index position 7)
    // AND that there is data in column A (as mentioned above)
    const rowDateObject = row[7]

    // Grabbing date components
    const rowYear = rowDateObject.getFullYear()
    const rowMonth = rowDateObject.getMonth()
    const rowDate = rowDateObject.getDate()

    // Here is where the filtering happens
    if (
      yestYear === rowYear &&
      yestMonth === rowMonth &&
      yestDate === rowDate
    ) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  })

  const outputSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet B")
  
  filteredDates.forEach(row => outputSheet.appendRow(row))
}
```

The approach taken is just to use the Native JavaScript Date functions to compare the dates and not try to use the `Utilities` to compare formatted dates. I believe this would be prone to some annoying bugs.

Then it makes use of Array functions like `filter` and `forEach` which take [Callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) functions. These are functions that run on every every element of the array, which in the case of `getValues` are the rows.

#### Result

After running this, "Sheet B" looks like this:

| Name | Value | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | DATA | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Carter | 0.124 | B | B | B | B | B | 5/11/2021 |
| Brian James | 0.568 | B | B | B | B | B | 5/11/2021 |
| William Watson | 0.185 | C | C | C | C | C | 5/11/2021 |
| Linda Richardson | 0.319 | C | C | C | C | C | 5/11/2021 |
| Virginia Edwards | 0.133 | A | A | A | A | A | 5/11/2021 |

#### Reference

- [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange())
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))
- [Date Object reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thank you so much!
It did exactly what I wanted it to do.
The detailed explanation was also very helpful. I would like to use it in the future.